# Trigger action values not updating in Database

Tags: before-trigger, database

I am new to salesforce and trying to play around with triggers. I have tried the trailhead exercise for triggers to set `shippingPostCode` from `BillingPostalCode`. Below is my code

```java
trigger AccountAddressTrigger on Account (before insert, before update) {
    
    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate){
        for (Account a : [SELECT Match_Billing_Address__c,BillingPostalCode,shippingPostalCode  FROM Account WHERE Id IN :Trigger.New]){
            if(a.Match_Billing_Address__c){
                a.shippingPostalCode = a.BillingPostalCode; 
                System.debug('a.shippingPostalCode'+a.shippingPostalCode);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

It prints the `shippingPostCode` in the log whereas I couldn't see the same when I query the Account object, its still shows null. Not sure why it's not updating on the backend. Can you please help?

Answer (score 2):

In `before` trigger you can modify the *instance* of records from `Trigger.new` without a dml, while to update records you got via SOQL you must perform a dml, no matter if they have the same Id: they are different *instance*.

In your scenario I think you don't need the SOQL, you could just loop over records in `Trigger.new`, check `Match_Billing_Address__c` then update `shippingPostalCode`.

```java
trigger AccountAddressTrigger on Account (before insert, before update) {

    for (Account a : Trigger.new) {
        if(a.Match_Billing_Address__c){
            a.shippingPostalCode = a.BillingPostalCode; 
            System.debug('a.shippingPostalCode'+a.shippingPostalCode);
        }
    }

}
```

Moreover in `before insert` you don't have the record Id, so the SOQL would return an empty list.

Anyway, in `before update` you can get the updatable instance from `Trigger.newMap`.

Comment: Yep, there is no SOQL query required here. The trigger context variables (trigger.new, and the like) contain the data for the records already. You'd only need to have a query here if you were trying to pull data from related records (like Owner.Name, Parent.Description, etc...)